# Can you unlock a car using a cell phone?

Tags: road-vehicles, mobile-phones

I have heard that it is possible to unlock a car using the remote key-fob over a cell phone network.

Scenario: Adam locks his keys in his car.  He uses his cell phone to call his wife, Betty, who is at home with a cell phone.  Adam holds his cell phone close to the car while Betty holds the spare remote close to her cell phone and pushes the UNLOCK button.

Will this unlock the car door?

Comment: Where have you heard this?

Comment: A few years ago a colleague managed to persuade me that this worked. Ten minutes later I was standing outside in the office car park while he phoned me and triggered my car's key-fob. Conclusions of this experiment: 1) This does not work. 2) If you try it in the office car park, everyone you work with have confirmation that you are, in fact, an idiot. My advice: if you feel moved to answer this one empirically, find somewhere remote. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [HowStuffWorks' page on How Remote Entry Works](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/remote-entry1.htm):

> The fob that you carry on your keychain or use to open the garage door is actually a small radio transmitter. When you push a button on the fob, you turn on the transmitter and it sends a code to the receiver (either in the car or in the garage). Inside the car or garage is a radio receiver tuned to the frequency that the transmitter is using (300 or 400 MHz is typical for modern systems).

And, from [Telephone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone) on Wikipedia:

> The telephone [...] is a telecommunications device that transmits and receives sound, most commonly the human voice.

And again, from [HowStuffWorks on Cell Phones](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cell-phone.htm):

> To start with, one of the most interesting things about a cell phone is that it is actually a radio -- an extremely sophisticated radio, but a radio nonetheless.

But, nevertheless, a cell phone intentionally transmits on [frequencies specifically assigned for mobile phone use](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cell-phone1.htm).

So, even though both cell phones and keyless entry remotes are radios, there are two main reasons why this is not possible:

1. From the transmission end of the call, **only audio** is transmitted onto the phone network (via microphone into an analog signal and then via electronic components to a digital signal, if a digital cell phone is used).  [Radio signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio) are light, and are not audible.
2. That audio is transmitted to your cell phone via cell phone frequencies.  Your cell phone speaker only emits sound.  As mentioned above, though your cell phone is a radio transmitter, and does emit radio signals, it only emits radio signals on cell phone frequencies for the purpose of transmitting audio.  It has no functionality for transmitting on any other frequency (like the band used by your remote), let alone for any other purpose. *(See the Wikipedia page on [Frequency allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_allocation) for information about regulation of radio frequencies)*

---

<sup>*Subjective and speculative footnote:* Looking at the technologies being used by cell phones and key fobs, it seems reasonable to believe that a cell phone could be built for this purpose.  However, it certainly wouldn't be a "mystery" function, since the device would have to have explicit approval from the FCC (in the US) to function on that band (check your key fob for its FCC approval ID).  I can't imagine any cell phone maker building this functionality, getting it approved, and then not advertising it.</sup>

Also, it's probably unlikely that it ever *will* be made due to more advanced, reliable, and propietary methods of unlocking cars (like GM's OnStar) are already in development or in use.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't had a reference yet to post an own answer. It should also be noted that modern cell phone can have a backup infrared connection, so that they also work in environments with a lot of radio noise. However, cell phone do not transmit infrared light either.

Comment: The speaker in a mobile would also be in-capable of reproducing radio waves, to further put this to bed.

Comment: The first celular telephones used a [completely analog system](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cell-phone4.htm), the voice channels of which could have, in theory, transmitted a key fob radio signal.  The problem is that those cell phones (at least in the USA) ran in the 800MHz spectrum (see link for reference), which is roughly twice the frequency of modern key fobs (I am not sure what frequency the fobs used in the 1980s though).  This would have likely required hardware modifications to the phones, and it would of course not work on modern, digital cellular networks.

Comment: @ESultanik I agree that in *theory* a phone could be built to do just that.  But the question is, not whether it is analog or digital, but how would the cell phone on the transmitting end "hear" the signal?  A microphone doesn't pick up radio waves.

Comment: @Renesis I agree completely.  My point is that if the phone itself is analog, then it could potentially "hear" the key fob signal by virtue of the fact that it is already listening for raw, analog radio signals over the cell network.  **If** the cell network were on the same frequency as the key fob, and **if** there were some sort of odd feedback loop or malfunction in the phone, it is possible that it could pick up the fob's transmission and re-transmit it over the cell network.  This is of course hypothetical and *very* unlikely.

Comment: @ESultanik is saying that, because cell-phones transmit sound using radio waves, **if cell-phones transmitted on the right frequency** it would have been theoretically possible to produce a sound that your cell-phone would transcode to exactly the right radio signal to unlock a car.  In fact, even in this digital age this would still be theoretically possible, because (due to the way radio works) **all** radio is necessary analog - cellphones have complicated [DACs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter) to make this possible. (cont.)

Comment: @BlueRaja - Ah I see.  But in this case your cell phone (at the car) is doing the receiving, and outputting sound (speaker).  It is outputting to its radio only what it hears on its microphone.  And you certainly can't get the cell towers to output on the band used by key fobs.  Imagine the chaos that would ensue! :)

Comment: (cont.) However, because the digital payload is encrypted in cell-phones, even *if* the cell-phone transmitted at just the right frequency (and [modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation)), this would still require finding a [preimage attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) on the encryption function, which, for any half-decent encryption, is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Renesis: presumably in that case the signal (which your cell-phone would have to receive *somehow*) would come from the tower.  I think that would cause the same choas as having the cell-phones on that frequency :)

Answer (score 15):

This was tested and busted by [Mythbusters](http://videos.howstuffworks.com/discovery/6532-mythbusters-cell-phone-remote-video.htm).

It is also listed as urban legend / email hoax by [About.com](http://urbanlegends.about.com/library/bl_unlock_door.htm).

The signals emitted by the car remote are mainly radio signals with a frequency of 315MHz in the US and Japan and 433.92MHz (ISM band) in Europe as explained in [Requirements of Remote Keyless Entry (RKE) Systems](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3395/CMP/WP-19). An alternative are [infrared remotes](http://www.ece.msstate.edu/courses/ece4522/projects/2001_fall/ike/documents/docfinal.pdf) which are not affected by radio noise generated by some machinery e.g. in industry, but require to aim to the car.

Mobile (aka cell) phones are only designed to transmit human voice or digital data like text messages. The frequency bandwidth of the transmitted audio signal is in the range from [3.1kHz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gsm#Voice_codecs) to [4kHz (8kHz sampling rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Full_Rate), which result in (almost) half the bandwidth following the [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)).

Mobile phones use a [normal microphone and loud speaker and an analog-to-digital as well as a digital-to-analogue converter](http://www.celtnet.org.uk/mobile-phone/how-mobiles-work-1.php) to record and play the transmitted audio signals.

It is easily understood that a microphone can not record either radio waves nor infrared (light) signals. Also the loud speaker of a mobile phone is not able to produce radio waves or infrared signals.

As shown by the above urban-legends link, this idea popped up as an email and following the technical explanation shown here can be safely taken as an hoax.

Comment: IF a remote sent IR pulses, a phones camera could pick them up (point an IR remote at most digital cameras and you can see it flash).  you could write an app that picked them up, and transmitted the code across to another phone.  If that phone had an IR emitter, it COULD re-generate the code.

Comment: @fred: Interesting concept.  Have you written an app for that yet?

Comment: @ooserwal - I don't believe car remotes generally use IR, so even if I had the knowledge/skills to do so, the market would be somewhat limited.

Comment: I'm always interested in how these urban legends get started. I believe this one got started when hackers demonstrated that *particular* models of cars that used *infrared* remotes could be hacked into using smartphones (such as Palm or Windows) that have programmable infrared transmitters on them (which were used for wireless syncing and business card exchange).  Clearly the story mutated wildly since then, but the infrared attack is real. Some Mercedes in particular have this, the receiver for the infrared signal is mounted behind the side mirror.

Comment: @Tim Farley: Or at least, *used to be* real at some point in the 1990s - most modern remote unlocking systems use a cryptographic challenge-response system, transmitting over the radio part of RF spectrum (amongst other things, to thwart these - essentially, message replay - attacks).

Comment: @fred To my knowledge, different frequencies are indecipherable on a camera.

Comment: @Allison: Well that's clearly nonsense for a camera that produces color images, since "color" is just frequency of EM radiation.  The reason a cell phone camera can't snoop on an IR transmission is that the modulation is much faster than the camera's frame rate.  One would need a phone with a IR receiver (sensor and demodulation circuit).  Those do exist, they'd either be advertised as IrDA serial port (which Tim mentioned, syncing and business card exchange) or as "universal TV remote" feature.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, I've learned something in the intervening decade :) Modern CMOS cameras don't actually sense the frequency of the light, rather they observe they have color filtered (i.e. R, G, and B!) light sensitive gates which accumulate charge when exposed. So, yes and no. They don't sense frequency directly but they sense how much red, how much green, and how much blue is emitted because human eyes are trichromatic and can't tell the difference between raw frequency and a linear combination of three colors!

Comment: @Allison: Yes, that's exactly correct.  Although still somewhat beside the point.  Modulated digital wireless transmissions are much more than a frequency envelope, so even if the camera did report frequencies with some precision, it still couldn't decode modulation keying at higher than the frame rate.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, if the car is designed that way**

I'm cheating slightly as I'm answering the *headline* not the detail of the claim. But there are devices that allow phones to unlock a vehicle. They involve fitting the car with a black box that connects to the mobile phone network and allows location and unlocking functions controlled from the phone.

I first saw this in the [London Evening Standard](http://www.thisislondon.co.uk/standard/article-23751154-unlock-your-car-with-a-phone.do) who reported that the system was developed by [Zipcar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipcar) for the convenience of customers using their rent-by-the-hour cars.

This is likely to become a lot more common as smartphones become ubiquitous.